# design a 90 degree hybrid coupler 2-8GHZ

Tags: quadrature, power-divider

I designed a 90 degree hybrid coupler in hfss, in 5~6 GHZ.
S₁₁ & phase difference are okay, but S₂₁ & S₃₁ don't match.

What change should I make in the form to improve matching between S₂₁ & S₃₁?
[image]

[image]

Comment: hm, can you tell us which port is which?

Comment: this is when you would use the optimizer

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I can only assume that these mismatches stem from the effects of asymmetry. Note that your <4.5 dB mismatch doesn't look all that bad!

you could ever so slightly adjust the angle of your feeds and see where it takes you, but you'll probably lose a bit of your nice S11 that way.

Other people avoid asymmetry [by actually making their ring round](https://twitter.com/ibelings/status/1084232856786866177):

[image: Ibeling's Butler matrix]

However, I have no clue how well you can achieve such a wideband match as you did with that.